# SQL: Condition in Left outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Election:

```
EID PID    PlanCode     Coverage
2   49791   DELTA        FAMILY
2   49791   LIGNA        FAMILY
2   49791   BSP          FAMILY
2   49792   BSP          FAMILY
2   49792   LIGNA        FAMILY
2   49792   DELTA        FAMILY
2   49793   LIGNA        FAMILY
```

relationship Table:

```
EID     PID
2   49791
2   49792
2   49793
```

table Desc:

Relationship: Employee has 3 dependents

Election:For each Pid, an employee chooses a particular Plan

Problem:

As Pid:49793 enroll in LigNa plan only, trying to add 2 rows for remaining plan i.e delta,BSP row

Can we do it as plan name is not fixed, but we know of dependents in relationship table?

Please suggest..

PS: Its working now using cross Join

Comment: Can you post what you tried already ?

Comment: HI user3440798. I would suggest that you add your attempts at solving this problem to your original post. Most people on SO like to help those who ask, but you do have to show that you made an effort yourself first. Don't be despondent because of initial downvotes or snarky comments: You will soon get the hang of getting the answers you want here! As per your question here: What have you tried, and what do you want to get as a result?

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong you are trying to insert the missing `PlanCode` for each `EID,PID` combination. Am not very sure about the link of `LEFT JOIN` usage with this question unless I missed something

```
INSERT INTO Election
            (EID,PID,PlanCode,Coverage)
SELECT A.EID,A.PID,B.PlanCode,A.Coverage
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT EID,PID,Coverage
        FROM   Election) A
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PlanCode
                   FROM   Election) B
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Election C
                   WHERE  A.EID = C.EID
                          AND A.PID = C.PID
                          AND B.PlanCode = C.PlanCode)
```